# How to wrap text within a column in R when printing to the console?

Tags: r, printing, console, word-wrap, pander

I'm trying to adjust the way R prints a data frame to the console. Specifically, I want to print a data frame such that the text for a column wraps after a certain width is reached. Ideally, I want something that looks like the following:

```
     v1              v2     v3
1  TRUE Some text         TRUE
2  TRUE Some more text   FALSE
3  TRUE This text wraps  FALSE
        after a certain  
        width   
4 FALSE Even more text   FALSE
5  TRUE More text         TRUE
```

Here's a MWE:

```
data.frame(v1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), v2 = c("Some text", "Some more text", "This text wraps after a certain width", "Even more text", "More text"), y = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
options(width=10)
```

Here's where I'm at:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the `pandoc.table` function in the `pander` library. It  seems to do what you are after http://rapporter.github.io/pander/pandoc_table.html

```
library(pander)
m<-data.frame(v1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), v2 = c("Some text", "Some more text", "This text wraps after a certain width", "Even more text", "More text"), y = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
pandoc.table(m, split.cells = c(5, 20, 5))

#>---------------------------
#> v1         v2          y  
#>----- --------------- -----
#>TRUE     Some text    TRUE 
#>
#>TRUE  Some more text  FALSE
#>
#>TRUE  This text wraps FALSE
#>      after a certain      
#>           width           
#>
#>FALSE Even more text  FALSE
#>
#>TRUE     More text    TRUE 
#>---------------------------
```